# Define LastRow of imported Txt-File to Excel

Tags: excel, text-files, vba

I have a simple Question (I hope it is simple).

I'm using a UserForm with CommandButton (ect.) to import a Text-File in my Excel-Sheet.
Is it possible to define the last Row that should be imported (like .TextFileFirstRow to define the first Row).

Greetings,
Morris

Comment: I don't know if there is capability built in, but VBA has text file I/O statements that you can certainly use to accomplish this.  See: [link](https://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/953655-vba-standard-text-file-i-o-statements)

Comment: thank you, I will have a look at that.